# Is it possible to emulate the "--allow-file-access-from-files" flag using a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've written [a simple extension](https://gist.github.com/josephrocca/22f7f06925583a8c6630d55276c129db) to allow cross-origin resource requests when the html file is running locally from a specific directory (my dev/sandbox directory), but I'd also like to allow html files that are running from that directory to be able to make requests to local files. So:

Is it possible to emulate the `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag using a chrome extension?

Comment: Yes, I guess, your extension needs `<all_urls>` permissions and the user will have to manually enable "Allow access to file URLs" in the extension's details on chrome://extensions page. Then your extension will be able to perform requests to file:// URLs and provide the results to the local page - for example by spoofing the page's XHR/fetch API.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks! Sorry for the late reply. I'm going to try this soon and report back.

Comment: @Joe How did it go?

Comment: @Jun I have been meaning to try wOxxOm's solution but haven't gotten around to it unfortunately - other projects have gotten in the way of the one that this question was for. I still do intend to give it a shot at some point.